# Opencv:: Convert Mat_< Vec3f> to normal 8 bit color image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, type-conversion

I was using one of the opencv laplacian blend technic to merge 2 images by following this code

http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/11/13/just-a-simple-laplacian-pyramid-blender-using-opencv-wcode/

The code uses Mat_< Vec3f> to store the resultant image. My question is how to convert back this resultant image into normal 8UC3 BGR image

I tried

```
blend.convertTo(blend, blend, CV_8U)
```

but that gives an error of assertion failed

I also tried creating a new color image of same size and then

```
blend.copyTo(newImage)
```

but that image has some parts colored, other parts gray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code snippet,

```
Mat_<Vec3f> blend;//fill it 
Mat dst = Mat(blend);
```

Fore more info read [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html)

Comment: this works....!!! copyTo also works, i just forgot that i converted my second image to grayscale in my previous execution of code.